# Nested dissection vs kd-tree

Tags: data-structures, trees, computational-geometry, binary-trees

Could you explain, please, the difference between the nested dissection and kd-tree. For me they look same representing a tree data structure for a distribution of points in a multi-dimensional Euclidean space, but with different labeling of nodes. Is there any more fundamental difference?

I will appreciate a reference discussing both terms. I have found that there is no literature covering both notions simultaneously.

Comment: Well, one difference is that according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_dissection), nested dissection is an algorithm to solve a system of linear equations and a kd-tree is usually not used for that. Do you want a comparison of the data structure over subdivisions of the space used in nested dissection versus the way data is represented in a kd-tree? If so, please [edit] your question to clarify.